# Continuation to holomorphic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let G be a k-fold connected riemann surface with boundary given by $k >2$ non-intersecting Jordan-curves and $\alpha : \partial G \longrightarrow S^1$ a continuous map.

Now i constructed a holomorphic map $\beta : G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that 
$$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta} : \partial G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\ast} := \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$$
Now we can multiply this map by $|\beta|$ and find a continuous map $g: \partial G \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$ \frac{\alpha \cdot |\beta|}{\beta} = e^{2 \pi i g}$$

My Question is: Is there a holomorphic function $f: G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which extends continuously to the boundary, such that
$$ \text{Re}(f) = g  \text{ on } \partial G$$

Comment: What's a $k$-fold Riemann surface?

Comment: A k-fold Riemann surface G is the subset of a compact riemann surface X which is bounded by k non-intersecting  curves, such that X \ G has k components.